# How do i send with "res.send" a Function result

Tags: node.js, express, faker

im new to express and was wondering how to res.send() a result of a function!

```js
function listarAll() {
  faker.locale = "en";
  const productsFaker = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    productsFaker.push({
      title: faker.commerce.productName(),
      price: faker.commerce.product(),
      thumbnail: faker.image.business(),
    });
  }
  return productsFaker;
}

app.get("/api/productos-test", (req, res) => {
  res.send(productosFaker.listarAll());
});
```

Thats my function with faker and i just want to res.send() the 5 products that will return!

Comment: Does your code not work? Your `listarAll()` function doesn't appear to be attached to a class or object so it's not clear how `productosFaker` fits in

Comment: Well your route path is `/api/productos-test`, not `/productos-test`

Comment: Well thats annoying haha, Thanks!